# Flex - display welcome screen on first launch with checkbox for never show again

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air

I need to display a "What's new in version x.x" Dialog with a checkbox to allow users to not show the dialog on future launches. Can anyone help me by telling me what I need to look up in the api, or possibly an example?

Comment: I've never used AS, Flex, or air, but is there not a method of writing to a file (Or preferably the windows registry if it's windows-only) and then reading it every time you launch? If the file says, for example "NoOpen", don't open?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a file in `File.applicationStorageDirectory` where you store whether the user checked the checkbox or not.

1. Every time you run the app, you check if the file exists. If it does not exist, then create it.
2. Read the value in the file and according to it display the message or not
3. When the dialog is dismissed, check the value of the checkbox and update the file.

You can even use that file to store other preferences of your application like in this [example](http://www.fliquidstudios.com/2011/05/27/reading-and-writing-files-in-adobe-air/).